# Docker compose can't installed on Ubuntu 22.0.4

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-22.04

I was install Docker Compose on my Ubuntu 22.0.4 with this command line

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.docker/cli-plugins/
$ curl -SL https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.3.3/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 -o ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
```

that process was running succesfuly and I write this command

```
$ docker compose version
```

after that command execute, nothing happened with my computer, then, when i checked my Compose Verison with this command

```
$ docker compose version
```

but the output is

```
docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.
```

My reference : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-22-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can typo in the command. Run this these two commands

```
chmod 755 docker-compose
./docker-compose
```

Also I would recommend downloading this command in `/usr/local/bin` directory.

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
curl -SL https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.3.3/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 -o docker-compose
chmod 755 docker-compose
./docker-compose
```